# What type of Network Switch+Router to buy for small (less than 15) computers and printers

Tags: router, switch, network-adapter

I want to upgrade our dlink switch and router to a new system because we are moving to a new office. Security, reliability, remote access friendly (I'd rather be manageable and controllable.), and if possible to have an offsite computer (from home) connected to the network. I managed them all myself and I have a QNAPNAS repository also attached to the network at the present.

I am wondering if someone can send me;

1- The best brands to purchase

2- and a general layout map on how to organize them. I would like to restructure the network and if possible set the QNAPNAS to be the domain controller.

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully ran a small office network using a [MikroTik Hex](https://mikrotik.com/product/RB750Gr3). It's a decent router, with good software, good management solutions and support for VPNs. We recently switched to a [bigger one](https://mikrotik.com/product/rb4011igs_5hacq2hnd_in) mostly because we needed more ports. The downside to MikroTik is their high learning curve - the first time it took me the whole day to set up.

If you want something which is easier to set up but still has good quality I heard a lot of good things about Ubiquity. Although I don't have personal experience with them.

As for network topology, that's a question for another site (SuperUser or Networking). In general go as close as possible to a star.

Comment: @Farsh I forgot to mention: the Hex doesn't have WiFi.